# Cypher. Request with an analog of 'while' or 'for'

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, neo4j, cypher

Please help me find a solution to the problem.
I need to supplement the result set according to certain rules, but the amount of application of these rules depends on the result set itself.

```
WITH {
       magicNumber: 100,
       minPercent:  90,
       anyFlag:     'N'
     } AS Result
MATCH
  (p:Percent),
  (f:AnyFlag),
  (p)-[:RELATION]-(f)
  WHERE
  p.value >= request.minPercent AND
  f.value = request.anyFlag
RETURN p.value AS percent
```

Result: 91.5, 96.3

And it is to this percentage that I need to apply my rule, which, for example, increases the received rate to 100 in increments of 2.

```
while (result <= request.magicNumber) {
  result + func;
}
```

Result: 91.5, 93.5, 95.5, 96.3, 97.5, 98.3, 99.5

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solutions using Cypher, I had to write a stored procedure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).